# How to use something like `std::basic_istream<std::byte>`

Tags: c++, io, std, c++17

This question aims for using `std::byte` with standard input-output.

Are there any plans to add proper function overloads for `read(_bytes)` and `write(_bytes)` to the interfaces of `basic_istream<CharT>` and `basic_ostream<CharT>` in a future standard? What reasons speak against it? I understand that the `CharT*`-overloads should be kept. What can I do to use `std::byte`? I currently define in my project functions

```
std::istream& read(std::istream&, std::byte*, std::streamsize)
std::ostream& write(std::ostream&, const std::byte*, std::streamsize)
```

These use `reinterpret_cast<>` to `char*` resp. `const char*` but I believe this depends on the size of `char`. Am I wrong? Is `char` always `1 byte`?

I tried to make `std::basic_istream<std::byte>` but it is missing `std::char_traits<std::byte>` and so on. Did anyone make this kind of thing work already?

Comment: The entire purpose of `std::byte` is to take away that kind of thing and strip the type back to a collection of `CHAR_BIT` bits. What problem are you trying to solve, that you cannot solve with `char`? Please elaborate on the _real_ problem. _"Is char always 1 byte?"_ Yes.

Comment: Well, I am reading a binary file and do some byte manipulations. Then I am writing a binary file. I thought `std::byte` is the proper type to use for that.

Comment: @Maikel -- the word "byte" in "do some byte manipulations" is not the same word as "byte" in `std::byte`.

Comment: @Maikel: It isn't. Just use the same type that we have used for decades.

Comment: It feels like your question has been discarded without good reasons. The type [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) is designed to access **raw memory** and do bitwise operations (incl. **manipulations**), which sounds exactly like what you are trying to achieve. Yes, we can achieve the same with streams of `char`, yet in certain situations `std::byte` would better model the stream content. You are not the only one wondering: https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/fe72kp/modern_stdbyte_stream_io_for_c/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Don't.**

Whether you're operating in "text mode" or "binary mode", what you are still doing fundamentally is acting on *characters*.

`std::byte` is not for this purpose, and that's why it does not have these features. Indeed, it was deliberately introduced *not* to have them!

> `enum class byte : unsigned char {} ;` (since C++17)
>
> `std::byte` is a distinct type that implements the concept of byte as specified in the C++ language definition.
>
> Like `char` and `unsigned char`, it can be used to access raw memory occupied by other objects ([object representation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object)), but unlike those types, it is not a character type and is not an arithmetic type. A byte is only a collection of bits, and only bitwise logic operators are defined for it.
>
> <sup>http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte</sup>

---

> Did anyone make this kind of thing work already?

No, everyone deliberately didn't, as explored above.

Use `char` or `unsigned char`, as we have done for decades!

Comment: `std::byte` would be the correct type for "raw" access to file storage, just as it is correct for "raw" access to memory storage.  However, the C++ iostreams all incorporate a translation facet and do not provide "raw" access, so `std::byte` is not the right type for iostreams.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Do iostreams use the translation facet even in binary mode?

Comment: @MikeMB: Yes they do.  The newline conversion, which `std::binary` flag disables, is a different feature.  Now, some implementations may provide, as one of the available translation facets, one that does nothing, but that isn't guaranteed and if there is one there's no portable way to ensure it is selected.

Comment: @BenVoigt The assumption that '_std::byte would be the correct type for "raw" access to file storage_' appears more correct than the statement in the answer "_std::byte is not for this purpose_". Sure, it is not for the purpose of formatted output, but the question is definitely not about formatted access. Yet, you also state that '_C++ iostreams [...] do not provide "raw" access_': but what about the streams unformatted input and output functions, such as [`read()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) and `write()`? They do seem **raw**

Comment: @AdN: As I explained in my earlier comment, unformatted I/O functions such as `read()` and `write()` still go through the translation facet.  IOstreams do not do raw (untranslated) I/O.

Answer (score 6):

[P2146: Modern std::byte stream IO for C++](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p2146r2.pdf) is a proposal related to your request. The status is tracked on [Github](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/860).