# How to use new std::byte type in places where old-style unsigned char is needed?

Tags: c++, vector, c++17, std-byte

`std::byte` is a new type in C++17 which is made as `enum class byte : unsigned char`. This makes impossible to use it without appropriate conversion. So, I have made an alias for the vector of such type to represent a byte array:

```
using Bytes = std::vector<std::byte>;
```

However, it is impossible to use it in old-style: the functions which accept it as a parameter fail because this type can not be easily converted to old `std::vector<unsigned char>` type, for example, a usage of `zipper` library:

```
/resourcecache/pakfile.cpp: In member function 'utils::Bytes resourcecache::PakFile::readFile(const string&)':
/resourcecache/pakfile.cpp:48:52: error: no matching function for call to 'zipper::Unzipper::extractEntryToMemory(const string&, utils::Bytes&)'
     unzipper_->extractEntryToMemory(fileName, bytes);
                                                    ^
In file included from /resourcecache/pakfile.hpp:13:0,
                 from /resourcecache/pakfile.cpp:1:
/projects/linux/../../thirdparty/zipper/zipper/unzipper.h:31:10: note: candidate: bool zipper::Unzipper::extractEntryToMemory(const string&, std::vector<unsigned char>&)
     bool extractEntryToMemory(const std::string& name, std::vector<unsigned char>& vec);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/projects/linux/../../thirdparty/zipper/zipper/unzipper.h:31:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'utils::Bytes {aka std::vector<std::byte>}' to 'std::vector<unsigned char>&'
```

I have tried to perform naive casts but this does not help also. So, if it is designed to be useful, will it be actually useful in old contexts? The only method I see is to use `std::transform` for using new vector of bytes in these places:

```
utils::Bytes bytes;
std::vector<unsigned char> rawBytes;
unzipper_->extractEntryToMemory(fileName, rawBytes);
std::transform(rawBytes.cbegin(),
               rawBytes.cend(),
               std::back_inserter(bytes),
               [](const unsigned char c) {
                   return static_cast<std::byte>(c);
               });
return bytes;
```

Which is:

1. Ugly.
2. Takes a lot of useless lines (can be rewritten but still it needs to be written before:)).
3. Copies the memory instead of just using already created chunk of `rawBytes`.

So, how to use it in old places?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to use something like `std::basic_istream<std::byte>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43735918/how-to-use-something-like-stdbasic-istreamstdbyte)

Comment: Can you not change your function parameter from `std::vector<unsigned char>&` to `std::vector<std::byte>&`?

Comment: @Galik this is not my function..

Comment: [This discussion](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13955624) contains some solid explanation for (on one side), yet also _hate of_ (on the other side), `std::byte`. I tend to agree with the _anti_-`std::byte` side more, as creating or using `std::byte` is just another case of C++ going too far in the name of "safety" (ie: type safety), which I find to be the cause of a great deal of confusion and clutter and mess in C++, further convoluting things. My preference would be to literally _never_ use `std::byte`, and so long as my C++ colleagues don't disagree too strongly, that's what I'll do.

Comment: Note: my specialty is embedded software. I'm not sure that matters though in regards to my opinion, but maybe it helps shape how I think.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You're missing the point why `std::byte` was invented in the first  place. The reason it was invented is to hold a raw byte in memory *without the assumption that it's a character*. You can see that in [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte).

> Like char and unsigned char, it can be used to access raw memory occupied by other objects (object representation), but unlike those types, it is not a character type and is not an arithmetic type.

Remember that C++ is a strongly typed language in the interest of safety (so implicit conversions are restricted in many cases). Meaning: If an implicit conversion from `byte` to `char` was possible, it would defeat the purpose.

So, to answer your question: To use it, you have to cast it whenever you want to make an assignment to it:

```
std::byte x = (std::byte)10;
std::byte y = (std::byte)'a';
std::cout << (int)x << std::endl;
std::cout << (char)y << std::endl;
```

Anything else shall not work, by design! So that transform is ugly, agreed, but if you want to store chars, then use `char`. Don't use bytes unless you want to store raw memory *that should not be interpreted as `char` by default*.

And also the last part of  your question is generally incorrect: You don't have to make copies, because you don't have to copy the whole vector. If you temporarily need to read a `byte` as a `char`, simply `static_cast` it at the place where you need to use it as a `char`. It costs nothing, and is type-safe.

---

As to your question in the comment about casting `std::vector<char>` to `std::vector<std::byte>`, you can't do that. But you can use the raw array underneath. So, the following has a type `(char*)`:

```
std::vector<std::byte> bytes;
// fill it...
char* charBytes = reinterpret_cast<char*>(bytes.data());
```

This has type `char*`, which is a pointer to the first element of your array, and can be dereferenced without copying, as follows:

```
std::cout << charBytes[5] << std::endl; //6th element of the vector as char
```

And the size you get from `bytes.size()`. This is valid, since `std::vector` is contiguous in memory. You can't generally do this with any other std container (deque, list, etc...).

While this is valid, it removes part of the safety from the equation, keep that in mind. If you need `char`, don't use `byte`.

Comment: Excuse me, still don't get it, is it possible to use in places where `std::vector<unsigned char>` is needed? Also, why don't I waste memory using transform with `static_cast`? The same data will store twice in the memory.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy No,you can't use `std::vector<unsigned char>` in-place of `std::vector<std::byte>`. But you can do a trick to make this work. You can pass the raw memory array. I'll add code for that now in the answer.

Comment: You can also use `std::byte{10}` to initialise it.

Comment: @Simple Right! Didn't occur to me  :)

Comment: The (only) other contiguous `std::` container is `std::array`

Comment: @Caleth and `std::string`.

Comment: I would use `static_cast<char*>(bytes.data())` instead :)

Comment: @JiaHaoXu I didn't suggest this because it's very dangerous and not safe at all. It's common to make template specializations to types, which won't guarantee the same structure of the class. It's much safer to just use the internal array.

Comment: Hmm that cast does not work for me: static_cast<char*>(&bytes.front()) - I have to use reinterpret_cast.  Is that static_cast really correct?

Comment: @mjwach Just noticed that. Didn't compile for me either.

Comment: @seanngpack There's nothing such as "void char*". I think you mean "char*". You can copy a char* array to a new vector of std::byte, but you cannot do that without copying the data. Google it, you'll find a million examples.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something that behaves like a byte in the way you'd probably expect it but is named distinctly different from unsigned char use uint8_t from stdint.h. For almost all implementations this will probably be a

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
```

and again an unsigned char under the hood - but who cares? You just want to emphasize "This is not a character type". You just don't have to expect to be able to have two overloads of some functions, one for unsigned char and one for uint8_t. But if you do the compiler will push your nose onto it anyway...

Comment: It's not correct since chat can be 16bits. There is stdint standard header with all int*_t types .

Comment: I think the assumption of a char ("chat"?) with 16 bits is not happening. See this link that explains it: [link](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/06/01/how-many-bits-has-a-byte/) So you can be pretty sure that CHAR_BIT is 8, type char has (by definition!) a sizeof 1 and it can store 8 bits, not 16, on today's machines.

Comment: Incorrect. It does happen.
For instance TI TMS320C55x:
type size (bits)
------------------------------
char 16
short 16
int 16
long 32
long long 40
float 32
double 32

Comment: OK, admitted there are architectures where a char is more than 8 bits wide. However then:
- Let's not discuss about if these architectures are "rare"
- As a char is the smallest addressable unit there cannot exist an int8_t
- This platform is not POSIX compliant as it requires int8_t
- A byte has 8 bits (not 16, this is a word then), see wikipedia
- So you do not have any 8 bit wide datatypes at hand - in that case it makes no sense at all to talk about a byte datatype, does it??? Discussion get's rather futile here, doesn't it?

Comment: Also, if you read my original posting I recommended to use uint8_t from stdint.h and I cited what you will **likely** (not neccessarily) find in there on common platforms. I did not recommend to do the `typedef unsigned char uint8_t;`yourself as it of course will vary with the respective platform you're targeting (plus you'd pollute the std-namespace which is illegal). And if you're on a platform that does not have 8 bit wide datatypes, be it char, signed char, unsigned char, int8_t and/or uint8_t then you are simply lost. So I cannot see what is wrong/incorrect with the original post.

Answer (score 0):

If your old-style code takes ranges or iterators as arguments, you can continue to use those.  In the few cases where you cannot (such as `explicit` range-based constructors), you could in theory write a new iterator class that wraps an iterator to `unsigned char` and converts `*it` to `std::byte&`.