# Why I can't static_cast char* to std::byte*?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-byte

I know I can use `reinterpret_cast`, but it seems weird that I can not go from char to "universal" type like std::byte.
Is this just unfortunate mistake/limitation, or there is a reason for this?

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/jqP8cT):

```
int main(){
    std::string s{"abc"};
    std::byte* ptr  = static_cast<std::byte*>(s.data());
}
```

Comment: For the same reason you can't use `static_cast` to convert between `char *` and `unsigned char *` - `std::byte` is a distinct unrelated type.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo `sizeof(char)` is per definition 1 byte, as `byte` is defined by `c++` as the size of `char`.  `std::byte` is also an enum with the same size as `unsigned char`, so you are in fact guaranteed that `sizeof(char) == sizeof(std::byte)` by the standard.

Comment: @Mestkon Very good to know. Here I am assuming `std::byte` is defined to be 8 bits. Thanks for telling me!

Comment: It's not so much a mistake or limitation as the entire point and purpose of the type. `byte`'s whole purpose is to be memory without being a character or arithmetic type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use new std::byte type in places where old-style unsigned char is needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46150738/how-to-use-new-stdbyte-type-in-places-where-old-style-unsigned-char-is-needed)

Comment: @SilvioMayolo -- to be absolutely clear: just like `char` and its relatives, `std::byte` is required to be **at least** 8 bits. It can be larger.

Answer (score 6):

Static cast only works between:

1. Numerical types
2. Possibly related class type pointers/referrnces (up and down).
3. Pointers to/fom void pointers.
4. Activating conversion constructors/operators

That is it.

Reinterpreting things as bytes is a reinterpret cast.

Comment: Which one of those four items on your list would you say "converting an enum class to its underlying type" falls, or would that be a 5th item?

Answer (score 2):

In C++20 where `std::span` was added there are now [`as_bytes` and `as_writable_bytes`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/as_bytes) that converts a `span<T>` to `span<byte>`. Internally it uses `reinterpret_cast`, but it makes the code a bit more readable/safe.

https://godbolt.org/z/zY9KPaz9K

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <span>

void foo(){
    std::string s{"abc"};
    std::span<std::byte> t{std::as_writable_bytes(std::span<char>(s))};
}
```