# Read file into std::vector<std::byte>

Tags: c++, c++17, stdvector, std-byte

I'm trying to read a file in binary format into a `std::vector<std::byte>`

```
  std::ifstream fStream(fName, std::ios::binary);

  std::vector<std::byte> file_content((std::istreambuf_iterator<std::byte>(fStream)),
                                        std::istreambuf_iterator<std::byte>());
```

but I'm getting this error (which to me looks like `istreambuf_iterator` is missing an overload for `std::byte`)

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::istreambuf_iterator<std::byte>::istreambuf_iterator(std::ifstream&)’
     std::vector<std::byte> file_content((std::istreambuf_iterator<std::byte>(fStream)),
```

Am I doing something wrong ? And if yes what is the best way to do this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47481231/what-is-the-purpose-of-stdbyte

Comment: @PasserBy If I try using `istream_iterator` if get `error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::istream_iterator<std::byte>::istream_type {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’ and ‘std::byte’)`

Comment: @ThéoChampion That is because there is no default `operator>>` that reads a `std::byte` from a `std::istream`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'm trying to read a file **in binary format** into a `std::vector<std::byte>`

You are using `std::istream_iterator`, which reads from an `std::istream` using `operator>>`, which performs a *formatted* read instead of a *binary* read by default. Use [`std::istream::read()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) to read binary data.

If you want to use `std::istring_iterator` to read bytes, you would need to define a custom `operator>>` that calls `std::istream::read()` or `std::stream::get()`.  But this would be inefficient since it would read 1 byte at a time. It is better to call `read()` directly to read blocks of multiple bytes at a time.  For instance, query the file size, preallocate the `std::vector` to that size, and then `read()` from the `std::ifstream` directly into the `std::vector` for that size.

**Update**: I just noticed that you are using `std::istreambuf_iterator` instead of `std::istream_iterator`. `std::istreambuf_iterator` does not use `operator>>`, so it would be better suited for reading bytes. However, it still reads 1 byte at a time, so what I said about using `std::istream::read()` to read multiple bytes at a time still applies.

Comment: If I understand well, you mean something like https://godbolt.org/g/ezWhp2 but this will not work if I use `std::byte` instead of `char` right ?

Comment: @ThéoChampion yes, something like that, and yes, it works fine for `std::byte`, eg: `file.read((char*)buffer.data(), length);`

Answer (score 4):

you should be able to do it like this:

```cpp
  std::basic_ifstream<std::byte> fStream{fName, std::ios::binary};

  std::vector<std::byte> file_content{ std::istreambuf_iterator<std::byte>(fStream), {} };
```

Comment: What you mentioned above is not working.

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'
  what():  std::bad_cast

Answer (score 0):

If you need an iterator based solution then even in c++23 it's not getting better than that:

```cpp
struct istreambuf_iterator_byte : public std::istreambuf_iterator<char> {
  using base_type = std::istreambuf_iterator<char>;
  
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<base_type::iterator_category, std::input_iterator_tag>, "Stronger iterator requires more methods to be reimplemented here.");
  
  using value_type = std::byte;
  using reference = std::byte;

  std::byte operator*() const noexcept(noexcept(base_type::operator*())) {
    return static_cast<std::byte>(base_type::operator*());
  }
  istreambuf_iterator_byte& operator++() noexcept(noexcept(base_type::operator++())) {
    base_type::operator++();
    return *this;
  }
  istreambuf_iterator_byte operator++(int) noexcept(noexcept(base_type::operator++(int{}))) {
    return istreambuf_iterator_byte{base_type::operator++(int{})};
  }
};

#if defined __cpp_concepts
static_assert(std::input_iterator<istreambuf_iterator_byte>);
#endif

auto read_file(const std::string& file_path) -> std::vector<std::byte> {
  std::ifstream input_file(file_path, std::ios::binary);
  return {istreambuf_iterator_byte{input_file}, istreambuf_iterator_byte{}};
}
```

At the same time, As Remy Lebeau pointed out, there is much more efficient way to read raw data using preallocation and `read()`, `readsome()` methods. My tests shows that it's 2 to 5 times faster this way, and practically as fast as `assign()`'ing [memory-mapped file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) for all file sizes from 5KB to 4GB.

```cpp
auto read_file(const std::string& file_path) -> std::vector<std::byte> {
  std::ifstream input_file(file_path, std::ios::binary);

  input_file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
  auto const file_size = input_file.tellg();
  input_file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

  std::vector<std::byte> result(file_size);
  input_file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&result[0]), file_size);
  result.resize(input_file.tellg());
  return result;
}
```

Comment: This looks like an illegal iterator to me, since `++` returns a different type.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That's right, thank you! I will add this to the answer.

Comment: I would check the resulting type against the `std::input_iterator` concept.

Answer (score -1):

unfortunately only **char** iterators are implemented in **STL**, so

```
std::istreambuf_iterator<std::byte>
```

will cause an error. so use

```
std::istreambuf_iterator<char>
```

instead.