# Do we have a Strict Aliasing rule violation?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing

Do we have a Strict Aliasing rule violation in this code? I thought that `int` -> `char` and `int` -> `std::byte` are OK, but what about `int8_t`?

```
int main() {
    int arr[8] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}; // Little endian: 10000000 | 10000000 ....
    int8_t *ptr = (int8_t*)arr; // Do we have a violation of the Strict Aliasing rule in this cast?
    ptr += 3; // 100[0]0000 ....

    cout << (int)*ptr << endl; // outputs 0
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: the cast isnt the issue. If there is one then it is `cout << (int)*ptr << endl;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule. Did you read this? Or this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing ?

Comment: I mean, the += 3 - moving a pointer to T as if it was in an array with no Ts there - could also be bad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```cpp
> int8_t *ptr = (int8_t*)arr;
> ```

This is perfectly fine and equivalent to a `reinterpret_cast`.
The cast in itself is never a strict aliasing violation; the access of the pointed-to object is. See [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/5740428) for more details.

> ```cpp
> cout << (int)*ptr << endl; // outputs 0
> ```

This is undefined behavior ([[basic.lval] p11](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11)) because you are accessing an `int` through a glvalue of type `int8_t`.
There are only exceptions for `char`, `unsigned char`, and `std::byte`, and `int8_t` is most likely an alias for `signed char`.

> ```cpp
> ptr += 3;
> ```

This is undefined behavior:

> For addition or subtraction, if the expressions P or Q have type “pointer to cv T”, where T and the array element type are not similar, the behavior is undefined.
> [*Example 1*:
>
> ```cpp
> int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
> unsigned int *p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(arr + 1);
> unsigned int k = *p;            // OK, value of k is 2 ([conv.lval])
> unsigned int *q = p + 1;        // undefined behavior: p points to an int, not an unsigned int object
> ```
>
> — end example]

- [[expr.add] p6](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#6)

What you're doing is effectively the same, just with `int8_t` instead of `unsigned int`.

> I thought that `int -> char` and `int -> std::byte` are OK, but what about `int8_t`?

The cast itself is always fine, but only `std::byte` or `char` have special properties that would also make `p += 3` valid<sup>(1)</sup>.

`int8_t` is most likely an alias for `signed char`, which has significantly less magical powers compared to `unsigned char` and `std::byte`.
See [the appendix on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77097674/5740428) for a summary of magical powers.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> The standard wording is defective and does not support that; see [Is adding to a "char *" pointer UB, when it doesn't actually point to a char array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47498585/5740428).