# Write a sequence of byte data using basic_ofstream

Tags: c++, c++17, ofstream

I have a `info_list` variable of type `std::list<std::pair<std::size_t, std::byte*>>` that I want to iterate and save data in binary format sequentially into a file. Here is what I tried:

```
void write_data() {
    std::basic_ofstream<std::byte> file("data.bin", std::ios::binary);
    for (decltype(auto) info : info_list) {
        file.write(info.second, info.first);
    }
}
```

The `first` of the `std::pair` is the size of the data that `second` pointer points to.

I'm not good with these C++ streams. The file is being saved empty. What am I doing wrong?

I'd like to avoid using C features to achieve this.

EDIT:

I tried using `std::ofstream` instead of `std::basic_ofstream<std::byte>` and it worked... Why `std::basic_ofstream<std::byte>` is not working here? Am I missing something?

Comment: I'd be interested to know how to do this ... but my general impression is that going outside the standard-defined streams (char, wchar_t) is not always as trivial as you would think/hope.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43738691/751579) is interesting reading (though it is 3 yrs old).  Keep using `std::ostream::write` until C++ is improved (or fixed, depending on your point of view).

Comment: On a side note, in the `for` loop, `decltype(auto)` should be `auto&`: `for (auto &info : info_list)`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Why? If both `decltype(auto)` and `auto&` are deducted to the same type in this situation.

Comment: @JoãoPaulo [What are some uses of decltype(auto)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109737/) Not one mention of using `decltype(auto)` in a range-for loop

Comment: Is there something in the standard that does not allow me to use `decltype(auto)` in a declaration since it's a placeholder type specifier just like `auto`? I think this code with `decltype(auto)` is well-formed. If it's just not convenient to use `decltype(auto)` in this situation, ok, I can agree with you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau also from the official cpp [FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#decltype-auto): "(...) However, decltype(auto) is not intended to be a widely used feature beyond that. In particular, **although it can be used to declare local variables, doing that is probably just an antipattern** since **a local variable’s reference-ness should not depend on the initialization expression**". So yes, "being legal" doesn't mean it's good to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you're missing: When using `std::basic_ofstream<std::byte>`, you are actually instantiating `std::basic_ofstream<std::byte, std::char_traits<std::byte>>`.

The problem lies with [`std::char_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits), since the Standard specializations (types for which the behavior is well-defined) are:

```cpp
std::char_traits<char>
std::char_traits<wchar_t>
std::char_traits<char16_t>
std::char_traits<char32_t>
std::char_traits<char8_t>
```

Unlike `std::ofstream` that uses a specialization defined in the standard library (namely `std::char_traits<char>`), your code uses `std::char_traits<std::byte>`. To proceed with such an implementation, you have to [provide the missing specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std).