# Serializing data into a C++17 std::byte vector

Tags: c++, serialization, c++17, boost-serialization, std-byte

I'm trying to serialize/deserialize data to/from `std::vector<std::byte>`. The code below shows one solution with `boost::serialization`, but I think this applies to other serialization libraries. The problem with the solution is that it uses use `std::ostringstream` and `std::string`. I would like to avoid those and avoid the `std::memcpy` asociated with them. Is there an elegant way to serialize the data directly into a `std::vector<std::byte>`?

```
std::vector<std::byte> serialize(const T& data) {
    std::ostringstream data_archive_stream;
    {
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive data_archive{data_archive_stream};
        data_archive << data;
    }
    std::string str = data_archive_stream.str();
    std::vector<std::byte> serialized{str.length()};
    std::memcpy(serialized.data(), str.data(), str.length());
    return serialized;
}
```

Comment: why you need a `vector<byte>`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43735918/817643

Comment: @appleapple because it's better to use `std::byte` rather than `char` to represent uninterpreted bits

Comment: @Garzet note that the `boost::archive::binary_oarchive` takes `std::ostream` which is actually already `basic_ostream<char>`.

Comment: you can probably create a `streambuf` (`basic_streambuf<char>`) that write directly to `vector<byte>`, but as point out by @ StoryTeller 's link, it may not be good decision.

Comment: btw, I mean more why you don't just return the `std::ostringstream` (and avoid the copy) from my first comment.

Comment: note: I'm not familiar with boost.